# robotframework: Element must be user-editable in order to clear it. when tried to enter date

Tags: user-interface, testing, automation, automated-tests, robotframework

robotframework: Element must be user-editable in order to clear it. when tried to enter date
I have a fields "enter date", i can not input the date 
message error is displayed:Element must be user-editable in order to clear it.

Comment: The element is probably disabled - you need to do some UI action to activate it (like click), or you might be targeting the wrong element. Please include more information - the html structure, sample code you're trying to goet it to work, in this form the question doesn't confirm to SO requirements.

Comment: Alternatively, this can be a custom element (Kendo UI, etc) which is not "supported" by the original Selenium Library - you might need to get some custom keywords to call a JavaScript or something similar in order to control your element.